# Notation for expectation of a random variable/general Lebesgue integral

Tags: integration, random-variables, lebesgue-integral, expected-value

Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is a probability space and suppose I have a random variable $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. By definition, we have 
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{\Omega}Xd\mu=\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)\mu(d\omega)$$

This question might sound stupid but I feel confused about notation:

Is it wrong to use $d\mu(\omega)$ instead of $\mu(d\omega)$ and in general, is there any difference?

In general, if I have a random variable $X$, is it true that for any measurable function $f$, one has
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\int f(x)d\mu(x)$$

In particular, can I write the expression above as

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{\Omega}xd\mu(x)$$

I would intuitively say yes, but even though I am ashamed of myself, I can't write down a formal proof

Hints, tips and suggestions are all welcome

Comment: For your first question, $\mu(d\omega )$ and $d\mu(\omega )$ is the same. For your second question, $\int_\Omega X(\omega )d\mu(\omega )\neq \int_\Omega xd\mu(x)$. Indeed, $\int_\Omega xd\mu(x)$ is the expectation of the random variable $Y(\omega )=\omega $, and $\int_\Omega X(\omega )d\mu(\omega )=\mathbb E[X]$. Since $X\neq Y$ a priori, there is no reason to have $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[Y]$. For your edited post : $\mathbb E[f(X)]\neq \int_\Omega  f(x)d\mu(x)$ for the same reason than previously.

Comment: @Surb Thank You for the input! I rephrased the question slightly even though considering your comment the answer is still the same. If you post this as an answer I'd be more than happy to accept and upvote it!

Comment: $EX=\int_{\mathbb R} x\,d\nu(x)$ where $\nu$ is the induced measure on the real line defined by $\nu (A)=\mu (X^{-1}(A))$.  I just thought you might be interested in knowing this.

Comment: If you integrate over $\Omega$, you have $\mathbb E[X] = \int_\Omega X(\omega) \,\mathrm d\mu(\omega)$. Generalizing what @kavi-rama-murthy noted above, if you have an $E$-valued random variable (that is, it's a measurable function $X:\Omega \to E$ where $(E, \mathcal E)$ is a measurable space), you can use the induced measure $\nu=\mu\circ X^{-1}$ (also called the push-forward, this is the 'distribution' or 'law' of the random variable and sometimes referred to with the notation $p_X$) to get $\mathbb E[X] = \int_E e \,\mathrm d\nu(e)$.  In your case, $E=\mathbb R$.